# Не открывается сайт со многих компьютеров

Tags: веб-программирование

Вообще не могу понять - со всеми сайтами все ок, но заказчик жалуется что у него иногда и у других не открывается сайт. Просто ресурс не найден. dinoel.ru. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Рекомендую написать в поддержку тем у кого регистрировали домен.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что он не соответствует теме, лол.

Answer (score 2):

Скорее всего, в DNS. Нужно пробовать общедоступные: Google (IP 8.8.8.8, 4.4.4.4) или OpenDNS

Answer (score 0):

Соглашусь с Дмитрием, что ошибка в DNS-настройках, уточнение, настройки именно в связке Регистратор - домен - сервер. 
Второе предположение: вы только что поменяли настройки, и они еще не успели обновиться у крупнейших провайдеров (до трёх дней)
Ещё раз пройдитесь по этому маршруту Потому как никто не меняет dns у всех пользователей.